# Swift Array updating Values

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using swift charts Library.

When I use this code this is what I get. Which is what I want the chart to look like.

[image]

```
func updateChartValues(totalCountY: Double) -> (LineChartDataSet) {

        let values: [Double] = [8, 104, 81, 93, 52, 44, 97, 101, 75, 28,
                    76, 25, 20, 13, 52, 44, 57, 23, 45, 91,
                           99, 14, 84, 48, 40, 71, 106, 41, 45, 61]

        var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = Array()

        for (i, value) in values.enumerated() {

            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: value, data: UIImage(named: "icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))

            print("Value: ", values[i])

        }



        self.dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "Bullish vs. Bearish")
        self.dataSet.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.cubicBezier

        return dataSet

    }
```

But when I change the array (2 lines of code) only one value is updated to the same position everytime and no graph is shown. I dont know how to make the array update properly. I want t to be able to update the chart with my totalCountY values. (Only 1 value is added on the chart of totalYCount with out the graph showing. I want all values to be uploaded.) The index is never changing from 0.

[image]

```
func updateChartValues(totalCountY: Double) -> (LineChartDataSet) {


        var values = [Double]()
        values.append(totalCountY)


        var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = Array()

        for (i, value) in values.enumerated() {

            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: value, data: UIImage(named: "icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))

            print("Value: ", values[i])

        }



        self.dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "Bullish vs. Bearish")
        self.dataSet.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.cubicBezier

        return dataSet

    }
```

Comment: updates one value everytime and not all values of value array

Comment: If you want to keep the contents of the `values` array you should store it in an instance variable of your object (assuming your two functions belong to the same object). Currently the two arrays have no connection whatsoever (except for the coincidence of sharing the same name).

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you create the `values` array with a bunch of numbers. In the second function you create an empty `values` array and then append a single number (`totalCountY`) to it.

So, there's only one number for it to work with. What are you trying to accomplish?